# Adding a slide to jcarousel scroller?

Tags: javascript, slider, jcarousel, scroller

Is it possible to add a scroller like this, http://imageflow.finnrudolph.de/ to jcarousel? All I want to do is to add a slider to move the content with... I don't want the left and right arrowbutton to move the content with.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with jQuery UI's draggable or slider widgets.

Use the events they provide to trigger a jCarousel event, like carousel.next(), etc...